# Set a readoly/InitOnly member field using Linq Expressions

Tags: c#, reflection, il, linq-expressions

Given a `FieldInfo`, it is possible to set a C# `readonly` / CLR InitOnly member field.

When and Why would I want to do this?
its for a serializer, I create an empty instance of the object type, and I then populate all the fields from the data stream.

To the actual question:

Is there a way to achieve this using Linq Expressions also?
the `Expression.Assign` results in a exception if you pass an expression pointing to the readonly/initonly field.

Or will I have to resort to IL emit to do this (faster than FieldInfo)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LINQ, but is there a way to assign init only fields at init time, i.e. when you create the object, instead of trying to do it afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, `Expression.Assign` checks the assignability of the field, and even if you could hack it to create the assignment expression, it wouldn't be verifiable and couldn't be run. Emitting IL is the fastest way to do it, and it would also allow assigning pointers (which aren't supported by LINQ Expressions). You can see [here](https://github.com/IllidanS4/SharpUtils/blob/master/Hacks.cs#L134) how to emit a similar method.